# What's the best way to add custom configuration variables in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, configuration, compiler-construction, variables, build

We have to deploy a flex app through a series of development tiers. We are not using Blaze_DS or LCDS. My data/service urls are tier specific and are currently embedded in AS files.  We'll be building the project on each tier.  I'd like to make them environment variables, but am not sure what the best way to do at compile/build.

Is there a compiler option to read in a custom-config.xml? or -myCustomVariable = value?
or should we just setup the build to select a config.as file?

Any help or direction is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is it a web (swf) or an air project?

Comment: Ok, I posted a possible for this scenario. I assume that you have a webserver that renders your html page containing your swf. So this server probably know the necessary data/service urls and can insert them into the html template

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion.  I'm aware of flashvars.  Are there any other ways to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web project you could pass the configuration variables using [flashVars](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_3.html). This way you can pass your data/service urls directly to the the flash object in your HTML file.